# How to translate from voltage in a circuit to a command on a phone?

Tags: circuit-design, telephone

Basically, what I am trying to accomplish is getting my phone to make a call (to a specific number, say, my brother's), when a certain voltage threshold is exceeded. However, I have no clue how have my phone execute the call. I'm stuck on the translation between circuit --> phone. Does anyone know how I can have my phone make a call when a voltage threshold is exceeded? It can be either an iPhone (IOS 13+) or an android (version 4.0+). I have an iPhone myself, so that would be the most practical.

Comment: I never do this, but you can put some conductive foam on screen and ground it to make a button press. Or push to screen with selenoid.

Answer (score 3):

There are several possible approaches, depending on your skills and time available. I'm going to assume you've already solved the circuitry that detects the voltage exceeding threshold. But how to get to the phone?

It's difficult (and warranty-voiding) to "hack" into the phone circuitry itself, so a wireless link using Bluetooth is preferred. I would start by purchasing a "Bluetooth Emergency Button", a small fob that allows elderly or disabled individuals to make their smartphone call a predetermined number via an app running on the phone.

Now open that fob, solder fine wires to the contacts for the button, and connect these to your voltage comparator circuit. You may have to adjust your circuit so it closes the contacts for the necessary length of time to activate the button.

Comment: Thanks so much for the button idea! That makes the bluetooth connection a lot simpler. One more thing: If I make it so that my circuit only gives an output when the voltage threshold is exceeded, will the emergency button work just by soldering the wires together? How do I find out what to connect (solder) the wires to?

Comment: You have to make your circuit create a "contact closure". It can be done with a transistor but you would have to know what voltage is carried by the button. If you're not worried about power consumption, a relay may be easier for you. Once you open the button, you can figure out which traces activate it. You can test that with a piece of wire shorting the traces to confirm correctness.